# Web API load testing

Tags: asp.net-web-api, jmeter

When I record script, my login page recorded as html. but other pages not recorded as html pages rather it shows as js and web APIs. I cannot able to record or create script using html url. Kindly anyone help what exactly the solution. I can able to load test only web API or any way to create script using html urls.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your application nature. The whole idea of web applications load testing is simulating real users which are using real browsers as close as possible so ideally your load test should exactly mimic the HTTP Requests originating from browser when user is doing actions according to application use case(s).

You **should not** be recording .js files as well as .css files, all images and other media (audio, video, flash, whatever), instead of this you need to configure JMeter to [download embedded resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses) instead of recording and replaying the relevant requests.

[image: JMeter Download Embedded Resources]

If you need to load test the API itself you can omit simulating browser and send requests directly to API endpoints, check out [Building a WebService Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-ws-test-plan.html) JMeter User Manual chapter for more details.